# Spring WebClient post request xml file as binary or as raw data is not working

Tags: java, spring, post, spring-webflux, webclient

I want to send a post request with Spring webclient. I want to send a xml file as binary or as raw, the api accepts both. When i use curl it is working fine and the xml file is uploaded, but in my java program i always got an exception. I cann understand where the issue is.

```
//Raw data with curl is working:

//curl -i -u admin:password -XPOST https://myapi.endpoint --data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' -H "Content-Type:application/xml;charset=utf-8"

// Here i try it in java (Spring) with raw xml data

byte[] bytes = new FileSystemResource(xmlFile).getInputStream().readAllBytes();

webClient.post()
         .uri("https://myapi.endpoint")
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) // i also tried text/xml and application/octet/stream
         .headers(h -> h.setBasicAuth(DEV_API_USER, DEV_PASSWORD))
         .bodyValue(new String(bytes))
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(String.class)
         .block();

// This doesnt work


// Binary data with curl is working:

// curl -i -u admin:password -XPOST https://api.com/endpoint --data-binary '@file.xml' -H "Content-Type:application/xml;charset=utf-8"

// Here i try it in java (Spring) with binary file data

webClient.post()
         .uri("https://myapi.endpoint")
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) // i also tried text/xml and application/octet/stream
         .headers(h -> h.setBasicAuth(DEV_API_USER, DEV_PASSWORD))
         .body(BodyInserters.fromResouce(xmlFile))
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(String.class)
         .block();

// This doesnt work too
```

I always got a webclientresponseexception, with status code 500 or 400:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:794) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at de.hbznrw.deepgreen.DeepgreenApplication.main(DeepgreenApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://myapi.endpoint
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 400 from POST https://myapi.endpoint [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:213) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.10.jar:1.0.10]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.10.jar:1.0.10]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.10.jar:1.0.10]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:684) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.10.jar:1.0.10]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.10.jar:1.0.10]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373) ~[netty-handler-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236) ~[netty-handler-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.67.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.67.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.67.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1704) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
        at de.hbznrw.deepgreen.service.AppService.xmlToMetadata(AppService.java:113) ~[classes/:na]
        at de.hbznrw.deepgreen.runner.AppRunner.run(AppRunner.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at de.hbznrw.deepgreen.DeepgreenApplication.main(DeepgreenApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Somebody has an idea and can solve my problem? Thank you!

Comment: do you know why `myapi.endpoint` is returning a 400? Does it log any reason why?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen i dont know why and the log is showing the same like the exception above. When i try with a curl command, it returns 200, but not in java.

Comment: @AlPecino is it 400 BAD_REQUEST ?

Comment: @AlPecino There is no issue with the WebClient code. Please check whether the request you sent is correct or not. 400 means your request data is not matching. I tried the same code with [sample](https://www.appsloveworld.com/free-online-sample-xml-api-for-testing-purpose#createtourist) without basic auth and it works. If I send the same request then it returns 400. So check the data you send.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with similar error when I was trying to upload video file: I always got response with http-status 400 Bad Request.
It happened because `WebClien` didn't set Content-Length header.

So you can try to set it here manually.

```
webClient.post()
         .uri("https://myapi.endpoint")
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
         .headers(h -> {
            h.setBasicAuth(DEV_API_USER, DEV_PASSWORD);
            h.setContentLength(bytes.length);
          })
         .bodyValue(new String(bytes))
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(String.class)
         .block();
```

Or try to do request with `RestTemplate`.

If it does not help, set up additional logging ([log request headers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls)), please.